# Make real people answer calls in Twilio

Tags: python, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

This Twilio is really awesome. I just have a question to which I was not able to find a straightforward answer.

All calls in twilio(Incoming and Outgoing) take place through webhooks.i.e you have to specify to which URL an incoming call needs to be redirected. Say suppose, once an incoming call to a twilio number is redirected to the URL, the set of actions defined in the URL are being provided as response to the caller.

Instead of this, is it possible for a real person to answer an incoming call to a twilio number. I am already aware of the "dial" verb where you can redirect the call to a different number. My exact question is whether is it possible to make a real person answer a call directly in the twilio number itself?

Comment: By "a real person answer a call directly in the twilio number itself", you mean a person, with a browser, logged in Twilio console?

Comment: @AlexBaban.. I know you cannot answer a call in Twilio console since Twilio is a programmable voice platform. What I need is, a functionality where, whenever an incoming call comes to a twilio number, instead of providing responses to the caller by creating a webhook and specifying actions in it, I want the caller to speak directly with the agent. I guess this might be accomplished by activating the mic and speaker of the agent while the call is coming in, so that both the caller and agent get to interact in real time. But my question is whether Twilio supports this? If Yes, then how?

Comment: @AlexBaban If I'm still not able to explain you, let me know so that I can put up a diagrammatic representation

Comment: Aishu , thank you for clarification. I don't know the answer but hopefully somebody from Twilio can give some insights.

Comment: Call forwarding to the number you can be reached at? If you need a more comprehensive service, you could use ZenDesk for support + have your twilio calls forward there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There are a number of ways you can connect an incoming call to a person.

The simplest is to provide a URL for your phone number that directs the call onto the person's real phone number. For that, your URL would need to return some TwiML, using [`<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial) and [`<Number>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/number) to set up a call to the phone. Like this:

```
<Response>
  <Dial>
    <Number>PERSONS_PHONE_NUMBER</Number>
  </Dial>
</Response>
```

However, you have specified that you don't want the call redirected. You have a few options here. You still need to use `<Dial>`, we just have some other choices for how to set up the phone on which the user answers the call.

You could build a soft phone using [Twilio Client JS](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/twilio-js) or the [Programmable Voice SDK for Android or iOS](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice-sdk). Once you have the client set up, you can then direct calls to it using the [`<Client>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/client) element:

```
<Response>
  <Dial>
    <Client>CLIENT_ID</Client>
  </Dial>
</Response>
```

You could get your users a SIP capable phone and use [Twilio's SIP registration](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial) to register the phone. You can then direct the call to that phone using it's SIP address and the [`<Sip>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/sip) element:

```
<Response>
  <Dial>
    <Sip>SIP_ADDRESS</Sip>
  </Dial>
</Response>
```

If you got a [Twilio Wireless Sim card](https://www.twilio.com/docs/wireless) then you could direct the call to a phone with that sim card using [`<Sim>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/sim):

```
<Response>
  <Dial>
    <Sim>SIM_ID</Sim>
  </Dial>
</Response>
```

These are just some ways you can connect a call to a user. I hope this helps.

Comment: Perfect! This is what I was expecting. Thnx!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a real person can answer a Twilio inbound call.  The way you do that is to Forward that call to the real person's real phone number.